# iOS with Accessibility enabled not working properly in iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, accessibility

Im trying to customize the talkback announcement in Accessibility, So I'm using `aria-hidden=true` for HTML element

```
<p aria-hidden="true" aria-label="testing">Testing content</p>
```

In Cordova android platform  its working properly (announcing the customized talkback if am not setting `aria-hidden=true`then  it announces the text am providing in `aria-label='Some text'` ).

But in Cordova iOS platform it is  not announcing default screen reading option provided by the `Accessibility` and the event  click,touch, tap , keypress not triggering for the tag which am setting  `aria-hidden=true`.

If i set `aria-hidden=false` then in  `Accesisbility` start announcing the default talkback of HTML elements like button,link and not text am providing inside the attribute `aria-label=Some text' .

So what should I do to enable custom `Accessibility` talkback announcement in Cordova iOS platform?